# how to find one element from one cell of a web table without using any locator like id,xpah,name etc. of that cell in selenium

Tags: selenium

I have one dynamic table. in row=1 and column=3 the value of the cell is 2. I don't know any xpath, id, name etc.

To use td and tr how can I get that value.

Sample table

```
WebElement table= driver.findElement(By.id("table"));

/* List of all rows*/
List< WebElement> rows = table.findElement(By.tagName("tr"));

int row_count = rows.size();

/*Looping rows*/
for(int i=0;i< row_count;i++)
{

 /* List all columns*/
 List < WebElement> columns = rows.findElement(By.tagName("td"));

 int column_count= columns.size();

  for(int j=0;j< column_count ; j++)
  {
   String celltext= columns.get(j).getText();

   System.out.println(celltext);  ///This will print all values inside the table.

   ////But I want only one value from one cell, suppose from first row and third column
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please add sample code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying if your `td` cell value is `2` and no other cell has value `2` then try this `xpath` :-

```
//td[text() = '2']
```

or

```
//tr[1]/td[text() = '2']
```

And if you want to get cell value try as below (Amusing you are using java) :-

```
WebElement table= driver.findElement(By.id("table"));
String cellValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tr[1]/td[3]")).getText()
```

**Edited** :- you should try to get text from first row third column as below :-

```
String thirdColumnText = table.findElement(By.tagName("tr")).get(0).findElements(By.tagName(td)).get(3).getText();
```

**Note** :- For more better solution, need to share your table `HTML`

hope it helps..:)

Comment: Please find sample table and yes, i'm using java

Comment: @padmajyotibora try with updated answer.. hope it works